# Why are so many HTTP requests sent to www.google.com?

Tags: http

I'm using Burp suite to see the requests my computer sends out when I go to www.google.com, and noticed that there were a lot of different requests sent. Why is this the case? Shouldn't it just be one GET request to Google's server, and then done? Instead it's sending maybe 10 GET requests and a handful of POST requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one GET request for the page (and more for every image, CSS, and JavaScript file), and then there can be many other AJAX GET/POST requests that get done afterward for things like updating the suggestions as you type things in, sending location information, or doing stuff with the cookies on your computer. Pretty much any time new information is displayed without reloading the page, there's an AJAX request going on. AJAX is also used to make expensive requests so the page can load faster. There are many uses.

Here's a tutorial for how AJAX works if you would like to do it yourself: [AJAX Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

**Note:** AJAX is a method of sending requests, it's not its own programming language. It stands for "**A**synchronous **J**avaScript **a**nd **X**ML."

Comment: I talk so much about AJAX here because Google is like the pioneer of AJAX, and so they use it an awful lot. It speeds everything up, and Google is such a big company with so many services like Youtube and advertisements that they have a lot of content and scripts to prepare everything.

Answer (score 0):

while it is hard to come up with a 100% answer to your question (I can not tell which requests your computer sends to Google) one possibility is that after the first GET request Google sends back a bunch of HTML/CSS/JavaScript. JavaScript is then executed on your computer (Client side) and might trigger another request towards Google servers. However, this is just one possibility.

Cheers,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Normally every element of a page is requestet with a separate GET. (css, images, scripts) 
So you'll hardly (never) find a site which is being loaded by one single GET-request.